# Fill gap on wood shelves?

Tags: wood, woodworking, wooden-furniture

How can I fill this gap in my diy shelves? I’ll be using wood screws to secure the shelf.

The gap’s less than 1/4”.

I was thinking of using [pieces of wine cork](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xwev.jpg) to even the weight.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pilot the ledger piece, when you add the screws to hold it down the shelf should draw down to meet it.

Comment: But then the gap would be on the other side.

Comment: The notion would be to use 2 screws, one for each corner, and 2 on the other end. If the it rocks on the ledgers it will take 4 screws to keep it tight.

Comment: I’m still confused. The shelf will be flush on one side when I use the two screws. But the gap will then be on the other side.

Comment: That's why one screw on each corner, through a piloted hole. I should have mentioned that at first, but the question was only about the one gap. I should have known it would only rock and create a gap in another corner. I see one of my comments had typos to make it difficult to understand...

Comment: As a matter of fact, since the wood is twisted, it really only needs one screw in the raised corner, and one more in the other corner that raises when the first screw is added. The other 2 corners will be pressed down in place tighter.

Comment: Thanks. So the gap would remain and the weight of the stuff on the shelf would be held by the screw?

Comment: The screws will draw the gap closed, the same way a clamp would. You could draw it tight with a clamp. Remove the clamp from the back and place it on the front where the gap is, tighten the clamp and drive a screw in to keep the shelf tight. Do the same on the other side when it lifts up.

Comment: Got it now. The thing is that I didn’t want to force the wood to bend since it’s 2x6” and it’s extremely hard.

Comment: Either one or the other will give if you want the gap to go away

Comment: @rbhat straightening a 2x6 with a clamp isn't that difficult, but if you don't want to do that then either, A) live with the gap, or B) buy/make a straigher piece of lumber. You can make it straight with a surface planer - taking 1/32 (or so) off at a time until you've got a nice flat surface. Do a search on flattening wood with a planer, because you can't just run it through, you need to support it so it doesn't rock...